# getting iframe height inside jQuery tabs returns 0

Tags: jquery, iframe, tabs, height

I'm having multiple iframes inside jQuery tabs and they are not in the active tab. Each tab contains an iframe. I'm trying to get the height of the iframe contents to expand the iframe height. The problem is the function alerts 0 if the iframe is inside a tab but works fine if the iframe is in the page body directly. Here's the iframe code

```
<div id="discussion">
    <iframe src="page path here" id="myFrame" style="width: 90%; 
     float: right;border: 0;" onload="calcHeight()"></iframe>
</div>
```

and the function

```
function calcHeight(){
    var the_height=document.getElementById('myFrame')
        .contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    document.getElementById('myFrame').height=the_height;
    $("#myFrame").css("height",the_height);
    alert(the_height);
}
```

Comment: Is the tab in question active on page load? If not, you'll need to use your tab mechanism's callback to get the iframe height when it becomes visible.

Comment: Like the above comment...the iframe needs to actually be visible (ie not be display: none or in a container that has display: none).

Comment: It's not in the active tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQueryUI's callback to get the iframe height once the tab is loaded:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        calcHeight();
    }
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Comment: load didn't work but activate worked please edit your answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot for your help